# NSRegularExpression to extract text between two XML tags

Tags: objective-c, regex, swift, swift3, nsregularexpression

How to extract the value "6" between the "badgeCount" tags using NSRegularExpression. Following is the response from the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><badgeCount>6</badgeCount><rank>2</rank><screenName>myName</screenName>
```

Following is the code I tried but not getting success. Actually it goes in else part and prints "Value of regex is nil":

```
NSString *responseString =   [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseDataForCrntUser bytes] length:responseDataForCrntUser.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=badgeCount>)(?:[^])*?(?=</badgeCount)" options:0 error:&error];
if (regex != nil) {
    NSTextCheckingResult *firstMatch = [regex firstMatchInString:responseString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [responseString length])];
    NSLog(@"NOT NIL");
    if (firstMatch) {
        NSRange accessTokenRange = [firstMatch rangeAtIndex:1];
        NSString *value = [urlString substringWithRange:accessTokenRange];
        NSLog(@"Value: %@", value);
    }
}
else
    NSLog(@"Value of regex is nil");
```

If you could provide sample code that would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I don't want to use NSXMLParser.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an xml parser to parse xml?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: No need of NSXMLParser for extracting just a couple of values ... I did got the needed Regular Expression "(?<=badgeCount>)(?:[^])*?(?=</badgeCount)" using the http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ online tool but unable to use the same expression in NSRegular Expression...

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you tried, and explain exactly what is not working about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Example:

```
NSString *xml = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><badgeCount>6</badgeCount><rank>2</rank><screenName>myName</screenName>";
NSString *pattern = @"<badgeCount>(\\d+)</badgeCount>";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                      regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                      error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult = [regex firstMatchInString:xml options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, xml.length)];

NSRange matchRange = [textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *match = [xml substringWithRange:matchRange];
NSLog(@"Found string '%@'", match);
```

NSLog output:

```
Found string '6'
```

Comment: If I want to get the value "myName" between tag <screenName> do I need  to create new regular expression or could I do it in the same.

Comment: It would require a new regex because "\d+" specifies one or more digits.  For a name you will need something like "\S+" (if there are no spaces in the name).  There is a more general regex that should work in either case: @"<badgeCount>([^<]+)</badgeCount>", that says anything up to the "<" character.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated. .... So that means I need two separate patterns 1.<badgeCount>([^<]+)</badgeCount> for getting badgeCount 2.<screenName>([^<]+)</screenName> for getting screenName.

Comment: Yes because the surrounding text is different.

Answer (score 5):

To do it in swift 3.0

```
func getMatchingValueFrom(strXML:String, tag:String) -> String {
    let pattern : String = "<"+tag+">(.*?)</"+tag+">" // original didn't work: "<"+tag+">(\\d+)</"+tag+">"
    let regexOptions = NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive
    
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: regexOptions)
        let textCheckingResult : NSTextCheckingResult = regex.firstMatch(in: strXML, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)), range: NSMakeRange(0, strXML.count))!
        let matchRange : NSRange = textCheckingResult.range(at: 1)
        let match : String = (strXML as NSString).substring(with: matchRange)
        return match
    } catch {
        print(pattern + "<-- not found in string -->" + strXML )
        return ""
    }
}
```

P.S : This is corresponding swift solution of @zaph's solution in obj-c

Comment: `"<"+tag+">(\\d+)</"+tag+">"` did not work for me, I had to use `"<"+tag+">(.*?)</"+tag+">"`.