# NSRegularExpression Check Content of HTML String

Tags: html, ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I get html string from server. If it's empty, we don't do anything. Otherwise, we show them on UIWebView. I can easily check with `.isEmpty` in a simple if statement.

```
    Services.getBusinessProfile(countryCode: countryCode, companyId: companyData.cId) { (req, html) in

            if !html.isEmpty {
// rest of the code
```

Problem is, sometimes I get empty  tag:

```
<span style=\"font-family:HelveticaNeue; font-size: 16\"></span>
```

How can I check the content of this  tag? I think I have to use `NSRegularExpression` for this, as this thread: [NSRegularExpression to extract text between two XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7661254/1137814). But I have no clue how to use it.

Comment: Use a proper XML/HTML parser. Not only will that make your life a whole lot easier but technically, regular expressions are not sufficiently computationally powerful for parsing XML/HTML in the general case.

Comment: I thought about it, but my senior decided to not to because it's only needed in this line :D

Comment: Your question it is unclear. Is your html consistent? I mean are you trying to get the string between `<span style=\"font-family:HelveticaNeue; font-size: 16\">` and `</span>` ? Which in this case would be an empty string ?

Comment: Hi Leo, yes it's consistent. The real content is inside the first <span> tag, so technically if there's no content between that it means empty. I'll update my question.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone ? By calling the equivalent in Swift, and then checking the `attributedString.lenght` (possibly trim before for white space) you could do it.

Comment: let attr = try! NSMutableAttributedString.init(data: htmlStr.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil); let result = attr.string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines); Then `if result.isEmpty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to retrieve the substring between the first span tag in your html text you can do it using range of string upperBound and lowerBound to get your substring as follow:

```
let htmlString = "<span style=\"font-family:HelveticaNeue; font-size: 16\">Indonesia</span>"

if let lower = htmlString.range(of: "<span style=\"font-family:HelveticaNeue; font-size: 16\">")?.upperBound,
    let upper = htmlString.range(of: "</span>", range: lower..<htmlString.endIndex)?.lowerBound {
    let text = htmlString[lower..<upper]   //  "Indonesia"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can validate if the String that contains the HTML text will result in an empty String once parsed:

```
func isEmptyOrBlank(htmlStr: String) -> Bool {
    let htmlData = htmlStr.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode)
    do {
        let attributedText = try NSAttributedString(
            data: htmlData!,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil
        )
        // Remove any whitespace and new line characters
        let result = attributedText.string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return result.isEmpty
    } catch let e as NSError {
        // Unable to parse, so assume it's empty
        return true
    }
}
```